# Drupal 7. Webform textarea with a html editor

Tags: 7, webforms, wysiwyg

I am using drupal 7.56
I used the webform module to create a custom form which contains a textarea.

I want to add a html editor to my textarea.

I tested webform_html_textarea but it's not what I need.

How can I configure CKEditor module for this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is fixed by enabling **wysiwyg**, **ckeditor** and **webform_html_textarea**

Thank you

Comment: I think you should try to improve your own answer, to better explain **How** it was fixed by enabling these modules (+ add relevant hyperlinks to those modules on drupal.org). After you do, please drop me an extra comment, I'd be happy to QA-read it again then, ok?